# Cypress + API auth

Tags: reactjs, api, cypress, okta, idp

I have a sample react app that uses an identity provider for user auth.  I am trying to automate user login with cypress, via the IdP (Okta in this case) API.

With custom cypress command I am able to authorize and retrieve user details and authorization token, but I don't know what to do with that information.

After receiving user details and token if I come back to my app root (which is configured as the callback url), it just tells me I am not authenticated.

I have configured a /profile page that uses a Secure route in React, which should only be accessible when the user is logged in.  If I get the token and then visit the /profile url, it still tells me I am not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post includes Cypress e2e with Keycloak, Okta, and Auth0. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/05/12/ionic-angular-jhipster

Code: https://github.com/oktadev/okta-jhipster-ionic-example/blob/main/ionic-app/cypress/support/commands.ts

[JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech) does it a bit differently by leveraging the URLs that Spring Security creates and calling APIs directly. It doesn't do any authentication in Angular, React, or Vue because it's less secure than implementing it on the backend.

Code: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/cypress/templates/src/test/javascript/cypress/support/oauth2.ts.ejs